# React Chakra UI modal only shows overlay

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm using Chakra UI in React with Typescript and having such a weird issue I trying to implement Modal with the following code in modal.tsx file.

```
import {
  useDisclosure,
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalOverlay,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalCloseButton,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function CustomModal() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal closeOnOverlayClick={false} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Create your account</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody pb={6}></ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme="blue" mr={3}>
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

once i click on Open Modal button it simply shows the overlay without actual content of the modal.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem and found that - For Chakra UI to work correctly, you need to set up the ChakraProvider at the root of your application.

```
import * as React from "react"
// 1. import `ChakraProvider` component
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"

function App({ Component }) {
// 2. Use at the root of your app
 return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Component />
    </ChakraProvider>
 )}
```

Here is the running code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-shape-hxmss) of your problem.

In `App.js` I wrapped the application in  `<ChakraProvider>`.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

First Check You Wrappped Your App With ChakraProvider If Provided

Comment: In the other answer: `you need to set up the ChakraProvider at the root of your application`